# Выборка по условию без крайних значений

Tags: php, mysql

SQL запрос:

```
$price_from = 1000;
$col_rooms = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads_appartments WHERE number_of_rooms = '$col_rooms' AND price >= '$price_from' ORDER BY id");
```

В таблице соответствующие `number_of_rooms`=1 - 3шт
У них значения `price`: 1 - 4520, 2 - 320, 3 - 4658.

Находит все в том числе и "2 - 320", но 320 < 1000!

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: То что `320 < 1000` ни о чем не говорит. вы же не распечатали запрос после подстановки переменных, может вы там в букве ошиблись и в переменной 0. Да и заключать числовые значения в кавычки нельзя, MySQL вас же может не понять и произвести строковое а не числовое сравнение. Так же это зависит от типа данных колонки, а структуру БД вы не привели

Comment: сравнение чисел как строк - '3' > '1'?

Comment: Убрал кавычки - ПОМОГЛО!:)

Comment: расширение MySQL давно устарело и удалено в php7. используйте mysqli или PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрал кавычки - помогло!

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads_appartments WHERE number_of_rooms = $col_rooms AND price >= $price_from ORDER BY id");
```